# JaegerUI not connecting to my service using OpenTelemetry Collector

Tags: spring-boot, instrumentation, open-telemetry, jaeger, otel

Hi i'm manually instrumenting my code (i'm a student) using Spring Boot, with JaegerUI and OpenTelemetry.
When I use JaegerUI I only see the jeager-query and its traces but not from my service.

[image]

This is my `otel-collector-config.yaml`:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: otel-collector:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true
extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
  zpages:

service:
  extensions: [ health_check ]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ otlp, jaeger ]
    metrics:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ otlp ]
    logs:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ otlp ]
```

And this is my OpenTelemetryConfig:

```
@Configuration
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OpenTelemetryConfig {

    @Bean
    OpenTelemetry openTelemetry() {
        Resource resource = Resource.getDefault()
                .merge(Resource.create(Attributes.of(ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME, "insaccati")));

        SdkTracerProvider sdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder()
                .addSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor.builder(OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder().build()).build())
                .setResource(resource)
                .build();

        SdkMeterProvider sdkMeterProvider = SdkMeterProvider.builder()
                .registerMetricReader(PeriodicMetricReader.builder(OtlpGrpcMetricExporter.builder().build()).build())
                .setResource(resource)
                .build();

        SdkLoggerProvider sdkLoggerProvider = SdkLoggerProvider.builder()
                .addLogRecordProcessor(BatchLogRecordProcessor.builder(OtlpGrpcLogRecordExporter.builder().build()).build())
                .setResource(resource)
                .build();

        OpenTelemetry openTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                .setTracerProvider(sdkTracerProvider)
                .setMeterProvider(sdkMeterProvider)
                .setLoggerProvider(sdkLoggerProvider)
                .setPropagators(ContextPropagators.create(W3CTraceContextPropagator.getInstance()))
                .buildAndRegisterGlobal();

        return openTelemetry;
    }
}
```

and this is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:6-jammy
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - dbdata6:/data/db

  otel-collector:
      image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
      command: [ "--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml" ]
      volumes:
        - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
      ports:
        - "1888:1888" # pprof extension
        - "8888:8888" # Prometheus' metrics exposed by the collector
        - "8889:8889" # Prometheus' exporter metrics
        - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
        - "4317:4317" # OTLP gRPC receiver
        - "4318:4318" # OTLP http receiver
        - "55679:55679" # zpages

  jaeger-all-in-one:
    image: jaegertracing/opentelemetry-all-in-one:latest
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "16685:16685"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "14250:14250"
    environment:
      - COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug

volumes:
  dbdata6:
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but it's worth pointing out that combine automatic instrumentation with manual instrumentation (it's even recommended to get the best visibility).
If you're using spring, you can use https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation or springs build in support - micrometer and micrometer tracing (both of which also support opentelemetry export)